# discord 8ball command doesnt choose the random answers set

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a discord bot and I was interested in making an 8ball command. I was writing it until I started testing it and whenever I do the command "_8ball " it copies the user's message that went in the text box. As well as if not putting anything in the text bot, my bot does "_8ball", is there a way to fix this? Here's my code :)
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgCXY.png)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgCXY.png)

```
    const answers = [
"It is certain",
"It is decidedly so",
"Without a doubt",
"Yes – definitely",
"You may rely on it",
"As I see it",
"yes",
"Most Likely",
"Outlook good",
"Yes",
"Signs point to yes"
]

command(client, '8ball', (message) => {
    const question = message.content.replace('_8ball ', '')
    const poggers = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)
    message.reply(question, answers * poggers)
})
```

Comment: what is the line `message.reply(question, answers * poggers)` supposed to do?

Comment: `message.reply`, like `message.send`, only takes one argument, which is a string. So either build your answer before you send it or use string concatenation directly in `message.reply`. You can read up on it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply)

Comment: @SovietSeal "question" specifies the question they asked, "answers * poggers" is supposed to get the list of the answers and then select a random answer to paste after the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is how you select your item and how you send your message. Your corrected code is this:

```
const answers = [
  "It is certain",
  "It is decidedly so",
  "Without a doubt",
  "Yes – definitely",
  "You may rely on it",
  "As I see it",
  "yes",
  "Most Likely",
  "Outlook good",
  "Yes",
  "Signs point to yes",
];
command(client, "8ball", (message) => {
  const question = message.content.replace('_8ball ', '')
  const poggers = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
  message.reply(question + ", " + poggers);
});
```